# Do LINQ operations return collections with the same indexes as collection being operated on?

Tags: c#, linq

If I perform `.Select()` on a collection, will the resulting collection share exact index values between the two collections.

Perhaps I haven't explained myself well. Here's what I mean:

```
int[] nums = new int[]{ 50, 100, 200};

var moreNums = nums.Select(num => num / 2);
```

Will moreNums[0] = 25? [1] = 50? [2] = 100?

Can you bank on this, 100% of the time? I always feel a sense of ambiquity with LINQ because of this. This is important because I have two lists where I can use a single index to refer to a pair of values between the two lists. I don't want my lists to go out of sync.

Comment: why use two lists then? pair them in a single class.

Comment: Well if not, then I will just have a for loop and manually use the index. What I am doing does not warrant a new class creation.

Comment: Yes, you can rely on the items being returned in the same order as they are taken from source collection.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, thank you for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Select` method logic is really simple: it takes one element at a time from you `source` collection, applies `selector` function and yields the result. That feature is called deferred execution - elements are fetched from `source` collection one at a time when they are needed and returned right after that.

`Select` could be written as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        yield return selector(source);
    }
}
```

As you can see, **there is no way to get items in different order using *only* `Select` method**!

In practice the method looks a little bit more complicated, but the logic is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it alwasy give the result you expected
I had done this code and it always work

```
List<decimal> MyList = new List<decimal>() { 10,20,30,40};
var Output= MyList.Select(s => s / 2).ToList();
```

Result in `Output` is

```
5  
10
15
20
```

Answer (score -1):

`25 50 100` in `case 1`.

`0 50 100` in `case 2`.

`0 50 100` in `case 3`. not `5 50`

```
int[] nums = new int[]{ 50, 100, 200};

var moreNums = nums.Select(num => num / 2);

// case 1
foreach (var item in moreNums) Console.Write("{0} ", item);
Console.WriteLine();

// case 2
nums[0] = 0;

foreach (var item in moreNums) Console.Write("{0} ", item);
Console.WriteLine();

// case 3
nums = new int[]{ 10, 100 };

foreach (var item in moreNums) Console.Write("{0} ", item);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: I do not think you have understand the question.

Comment: I'm sorry that there has been a misunderstanding.